# In PHP, how can I get the current filepath in seperate values?

Tags: php

Right now I'm using

```
$file = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
```

to get the current filepath.. but what I really want is to get each directory in a seperate value, rather than the entire path in one value.

To be precise... I have a filesystem that basically works like

```
website.com/x/y/file.php
website.com/x/z/file.php
website.com/x/file.php
```

And I was wondering if there was a method that allowed me to get all of those directories in seperate values.

For example, if I do

```
echo $dirone . "/n" . $dirtwo . "/n" . $file;
```

That it'll end up showing as

```
x
y
file.php
```

in the case of

```
website.com/x/y/file.php
```

or, alternatively, end up showing as

```
x

file.php
```

in the case of

```
website.com/x/file.php
```

I'm honestly not sure how to pull this off. I've found methods to at least extract ONLY the filename, but that leaves me without the rest of the directories.

Comment: Sidenote: Use `"\n"` instead of `"/n"`

Comment: That really matter? I've been taught to use forward slash..

Comment: It's what PHP.net suggests and have been that since I started getting into PHP a couple of years ago and have been corrected once. But hey, if it works ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$files = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    printf("%s\n", $file);
}
```

The DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant is important when dealing with paths given by the operating system, since Windows will give you '\' and unixes '/'.

Comment: @alex it does, but I have heard (rumor alert!) that it has a performance cost. I'm tempted to ask another SO question about that, after some research. (The context of this comment was about Windows automatically converting '/' to '\'.)

Comment: Tried this with $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] replacing $path.. Works great! Thanks for the help xrash and @alex. :)